# How to compute the moments of the maximum of two independent inverse Gaussian random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $X,Y\sim \text{InverseGaussian}(\mu,\lambda)$ be independent with the standard parametrization (from wikipedia).

Is it possible to get an explicit expression for

$E[\max(X,Y)]$ and $E[(\max(X,Y))^2]\,$?

Comment: In general, given $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ i.i.d. do you know how to find the distribution of $\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n} X_i$?

Comment: Yes, I know how, that's not the issue.